# Create std::chrono::zoned_time from zone and time

Tags: c++, timezone, c++-chrono

I have a datetime in a platonic sense, i.e some date and time (like 18th of January 2022 15:15:00) and I know in which timezone it represent something, e.g "Europe/Moscow"

I want to create `std::chrono::zoned_time`. Is is possible?
I looked at [the constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/zoned_time) and it seems all of them require either `sys_time` or `local_time` which is not what I have.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Does `zoned_time zt("Antarctica/Casey", sys_days{2021y/September/15d}+16h+45min);` do what you want?

Comment: @Passerby as far as I understand it'll convert time from system time to my tz, won't it?

Comment: You're going to need to nail down the year before you can create a `zoned_time`.  Once you have a year, you can create a `local_time` and then use that to create a `zoned_time`.  Otherwise you can store a `{time_zone*, month_day, seconds}` structure of your own making.

Comment: @HowardHinnant, I do have a year (forgot to mention it in the question). Now, if I try to pass local_time, won't it be interpreted as local time on my machine (as opposite to time in the tmezone)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    std::chrono::zoned_time zt{"Europe/Moscow",
        std::chrono::local_days{18d/std::chrono::January/2022} + 15h + 15min};
    std::cout << zt << '\n';
}
```

`local_time` isn't necessarily the computer's local time.  It is *a* local time that has not yet been associated with a time zone.  When you construct a `zoned_time`, you associate a local time with a time zone.

The above program prints out:

```
2022-01-18 15:15:00 MSK
```

So you can think of this as the identity function.  But in reality you can also get the UTC time out of `zt` with `.get_sys_time()`.  And you can also use `zt` as the "time point" to construct another `zoned_time`:

```
std::chrono::zoned_time zt2{"America/New_York", zt};
std::cout << zt2 << '\n';
```

Output:

```
2022-01-18 07:15:00 EST
```

`zt2` will have the same `sys_time` (UTC) as `zt`.  This makes it handy to set up international video conferences (for example).

Comment: Thanks. The first sentence is what I was missing. A bit unexpected name for a class

Comment: Yeah, that one was tough to name, and quite a bit of time was spent on that.