# How do i convert gmt time to other timezones in c++

Tags: c++

I have wrote a basic code to get the gmt time and i want to add specific hours to get another timezone how do i do that? (if there is any simpler way to do this that will work too)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    time_t tim = time(0);
    tm* timenow = gmtime(&tim);

    std::cout << "time in gmt is " << timenow->tm_hour << ":" << timenow->tm_min << ":" << timenow->tm_sec << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/calendar-and-time-zone-in-c-20-time-zones

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70759851/4641116

Comment: @Eljay it shows me an error saying "namespace std::chrono has no member "zoned_time"" and "namespace std::chrono has no member "local_days" " :/

Comment: Perhaps you don't have C++20 or C++23 (or C++2b or C++latest) selected as your language with your compiler.

Comment: @Eljay how do i do that?

Comment: You did not specify, which compiler or IDE you are using. (And there should be lots of search results.)

Comment: I select C++20 with my **clang** compiler by `clang++ -std=c++20`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clang/libc++/libstdc++ isn't yet fully supporting the C++20 `<chrono>` specification.  However there exists a [free, open-source preview of this part of C++20](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) that works with C++11/14/17.  It exists in `namespace date` rather than `namespace std::chrono`, but otherwise is a pretty good approximation of the C++20 spec.

It consists of one source file, tz.cpp, that must be compiled with your source.  On macOS and linux you can define this configuration macro: `USE_OS_TZDB` to use the time zone database provided by your OS.  An easy way to do this is to put `-DUSE_OS_TZDB=1` on the compile command line.

[Here are complete setup instructions.](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation)

Here is example code that prints out the local time in several timezones (along with UTC):

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto timenow = system_clock::now();
    auto fmt = "%F %T %Z\n";
    cout << "UTC              : " << format(fmt, timenow);
    cout << "America/New_York : " << format(fmt, zoned_time{"America/New_York", timenow});
    cout << "Europe/London    : " << format(fmt, zoned_time{"Europe/London", timenow});
    cout << "Asia/Tokyo       : " << format(fmt, zoned_time{"Asia/Tokyo", timenow});
}
```

I compiled this on macOS using:

```
clang++ test.cpp -std=c++17 -I../date/include ../date/src/tz.cpp -DUSE_OS_TZDB=1
```

This just output for me:

```
UTC              : 2022-04-30 12:54:43.963126 UTC
America/New_York : 2022-04-30 08:54:43.963126 EDT
Europe/London    : 2022-04-30 13:54:43.963126 BST
Asia/Tokyo       : 2022-04-30 21:54:43.963126 JST
```

---

The latest Visual Studio with the option `/std:c++latest` is shipping the C++20 version of chrono.  The above example slightly changes:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto timenow = system_clock::now();
    cout << "UTC              : " << format("{:%F %T %Z}\n", timenow);
    cout << "America/New_York : " << format("{:%F %T %Z}\n", zoned_time{"America/New_York", timenow});
    cout << "Europe/London    : " << format("{:%F %T %Z}\n", zoned_time{"Europe/London", timenow});
    cout << "Asia/Tokyo       : " << format("{:%F %T %Z}\n", zoned_time{"Asia/Tokyo", timenow});
}
```

1. Drop `#include "date/tz.h"`
2. Add `#include <format>`
3. Drop `using namespace date;`
4. Prefix the `fmt` string with `{:` and postfix it with `}`.
5. Inline the `fmt` string with each call to `format`.

I don't know why step 5 is needed.  That looks like a bug in `<format>` to me, but I'm not positive.

---

Here is a way to programmatically list all of the time zone names your system provides:

```
for (auto& tz : get_tzdb().zones)
    cout << tz.name() << '\n';
for (auto& tz : get_tzdb().links)
    cout << tz.name() << '\n';
```

It is also possible to provide user-written time zones.  Here is an example of a user-written [POSIX time zone](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/ptz.h).

Comment: i only get output of UTC and then errors

" error C2780: 'unknown-type date::format(const std::locale &,const CharT *,const Streamable &)': expects 3 arguments - 1 provided "

" message : see declaration of 'date::format' " (im on windows and visual studio 2022 if that helps)

Comment: I've updated my answer for use with visual studio 2022.

Comment: im getting errors saying " identifier 'format' is undefined " , " identifier 'zoned_time' is undefined " , " 'zoned_time': undeclared variable "

Comment: Did you set `/std:c++latest`?  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xYE4PcTEr

Comment: ah my bad, it works now. Is there a way to add more timezones?

Comment: Here is a convenient list of IANA time zone names: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones  I'm unsure if you are asking for this list, or if you are asking something else.

Comment: yup that exactly. Thanks!