# Converting time to local zone time: issue with hh_ss_mm template args (C++ 14)

Tags: c++, date, templates, c++14, c++-chrono

I'm using C++14 and the famous [Date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) by @HowardHinnant

I'm trying to convert a GMT (UTC) time to the time inside of some timezone. I need to have it in the `tm` struct.

All seems good except I can't seem to properly construct the `hms` object. My template arguments mismatch.

```
tm Time_hrv::gmtTM_to_timezoneTM(const tm& timeTM_gmt, const std::string& wanted_timezoneStr){
    assert(timeTM_gmt.tm_year < 1000);// the year of tm should be relative to 1900. For example, 2020 should be 120.
    assert(timeTM_gmt.tm_mon < 12);// [0,11]
    assert(timeTM_gmt.tm_mday > 0 && timeTM_gmt.tm_mday<=31);// [0,31]

       time_t timeT_gmt = Time_hrv::timeTM_to_timeT(timeTM_gmt);
    auto chronoTime_gmt = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(timeT_gmt);

    const date::time_zone* wanted_timeZone =  timeZone_fromString(wanted_timezoneStr);
    
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/70759851/9007125
    //NOTICE: local_time isn't necessarily the computer's local time. 
    //It is a local time that has not yet been associated with a time zone. 
    //When you construct a zoned_time, you associate a local time with a time zone.
    auto lt = wanted_timeZone->to_local(chronoTime_gmt);
    auto localDay = date::floor<date::days>(lt);

    date::year_month_day ymd{ localDay };
    date::hh_mm_ss<std::chrono::milliseconds> hms{ lt - localDay };  //<--- error here
    tm result = {0};
    result.tm_year = int{ymd.year()} - 1900;
    result.tm_mon = unsigned{ymd.month()} -1;
    result.tm_mday = unsigned{ymd.day()};
    result.tm_hour = (int)hms.hours().count();
    result.tm_min = (int)hms.minutes().count();
    result.tm_sec = (int)hms.seconds().count();
    return result;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is chrono giving you a bad error message for a real problem:  You are attempting to silently truncate a fine precision expression (`lt - localDay`) to a coarser precision (`milliseconds`).

The expression `lt - localDay` is a type that has precision of `system_clock::duration`, which is somewhere between `microseconds` and `nanoseconds` depending on your platform.  This is true, even though the source (and thus the value) of `chronoTime_gmt` only has precision of `seconds` at run time.

The easiest fix is to recognize that anything coming from a `tm` is at best `seconds` precision by truncating to `seconds` precision early:

```
auto chronoTime_gmt = date::floor<std::chrono::seconds>                    
                          (std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(timeT_gmt));
```

Now `chronoTime_gmt` has type `time_point<system_clock, seconds>`.  And therefore the later expression `lt - localDay` will also have type `seconds`, which will implicitly convert to the `milliseconds` precision of your `hh_mm_ss`.

A suggestion is to also use `seconds` for the template parameter of your `hh_mm_ss` since the `milliseconds` precision goes unused.  This won't change correctness or performance of your code, but the reader of your code will no longer spend time wondering why you chose `milliseconds` and then didn't use it.

Comment: Aside: It can be clumsy to convert from a UTC `tm` to a chrono `time_point` via a `time_t` as done in this question. This involves a common, but non-standard API often named `timegm`, which converts a `tm` to a `time_t` (without involving time zones), then you have to convert the `time_t` to a `system_clock::time_point`. Here is a utility that does it in one step, and the result is a `time_point<system_clock, seconds>` so you don't have to do the manual truncation to seconds precision:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#converting-from-a-tm