# c++ construct a std:chrono / date:: zoned time (adding hours, minutes?)

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I found this

[Create std::chrono::zoned_time from zone and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70755499/create-stdchronozoned-time-from-zone-and-time)

and I'm not sure if it works in all circumstances.

I'm not sure if 10 January 2023 22:15 is always 10 January 2023 + 22h + 15 min

And I'm thinking of some corner cases where for example we are in the middle of taking into account a leap second or there has been some update of tzdata.

Comment: Instead of linking to "it", please include the relevant code in your question, so that it's complete even if the linked material isn't available.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`zoned_time` is effectively a pairing of a `const time_zone*` and a `sys_time` of some `duration`:  http://eel.is/c++draft/time.zone.zonedtime

`sys_time` is a `time_point` based on `system_clock`:  http://eel.is/c++draft/time.syn

`system_clock` models [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which does not include leap seconds: http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system#overview-1

If you would like to compute with leap seconds, that is possible with `utc_clock`:  http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.utc.overview#1

The time zone database may be updatable on your platform (or may not be).  However it will not update during your application's run unless your application explicitly asks for it using `reload_tzdb`: http://eel.is/c++draft/time.zone.db.remote

Here is a brief article on dealing with the issue of updating the time zone database while the application is running: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#tzdb_manage

Comment: So supposing I don't have to deal with threads and tz database don't act retroactively and I'm not interested in leap seconds there are no other circumstances where a date + a duration is going to be different from a date and a time.

Comment: If it is a UTC date + duration, you can take it to the bank.  If it is a local date + duration, the result can have 0, 1 or 2 mappings to UTC, depending on the date time and depending on the time zone.  Most of the time there is a unique (1) mapping.  But not always.  The chrono library will detect such things and you will have choices on how to deal with it.  The default behavior for 0 or 2 mappings is to throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks. I guess you're referring to this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/nonexistent_local_time and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/choose