# Create std::chrono::zoned_time from zone and time from function parameters

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I was about to ask the original question ([Create std::chrono::zoned_time from zone and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70755499/create-stdchronozoned-time-from-zone-and-time)), fortunately it didn't take me long to find it.

That accepted answer is near perfect however even after an hour of staring into cppreference.com and googling I'm unable to find a simple example which would do exactly that but programmatically, i.e. something like

```cpp
std::chrono::zoned_time get_zt(const std::string& location, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minutes, int seconds);
```

I'll take also

```cpp
std::chrono::zoned_time get_zt(const std::string& location, const std::string& time_str);
```

if it doesn't use `std::chrono::parse` or `std::chrono::from_stream` (they seem to be still missing in my g++).

The goal is still the same -- being able to specify other-than-local time zone *and* time and then work with it (e.g. "how many seconds since the epoch had passed in time zone foo if *their* local time was bar?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```cpp
auto get_zt(const std::string& location, int year, int month, int day, int hour,
            int minutes, int seconds) {
    
    auto ymd = std::chrono::year(year) / std::chrono::month(month) /
               std::chrono::day(day);

    auto ld = std::chrono::local_days{ymd} + std::chrono::hours(hour) +
              std::chrono::minutes(minutes) + std::chrono::seconds(seconds);
    
    std::chrono::zoned_time zt{location, ld};
    
    return zt;
}
```

Example usage:

```cpp
int main() {
    auto lzt = get_zt("Europe/Stockholm", 2023, 11, 12, 22, 19, 44);

    std::cout << lzt << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2023-11-12 22:19:44 CET
```

Comment: Indeed, works a treat. As simple as I had hoped for.